# Get image center point

Tags: image

I added an image normally (`Shift + A > Empty > Image`) and the image's origin is at world (0,0,0), then I scaled the image to make it bigger.

The origin of the image is at its bottom-left corner, I tried to move it to the center of the image but it didn't seem to be possible.

The only property of the image I can see is its origin, so I'd like to know: **how to find out the world point that represents the center of this image?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the empty tab, set the offset values to -0.5 for X and Y. This will center the image. The world position of the empty now equals the center point of your image.

[image]